# Who were the faceless mooks?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-trek, star-trek-beyond

In [Star Trek Beyond](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2660888/), Krall's back story states that only 3 were left. So who are the majority of his army? They didn't seem to be drones or machines. This was unexplained as far as I could tell.

Comment: i dont know how spoilers work and my answer is 100& spoilers

Comment: @himarm spoilers here are expected. Maybe spoiler the quotes but otherwise answer as best you can.

Answer (score 3):

Krall states that they were machines (drones) in his fight with Kirk in the air duct at the end. This helps explain why they blew up when the Beastie Boys were pumped into their system.

He says something like this (remembered quote):

> Only 3 of us survived, on this alien planet with advanced technology, drones, and life enhancing tech.

Comment: I don't think so. The explosions were the navigation systems of the ships going haywire crashing into each other when the *"high frequency"* signal was injected causing interference. Unless you have word of God saying hey were drones...

Comment: well im 100% for sure there drones, whether it was becasue they were drones they crashed im not 100%

Comment: Yes, but is there evidence that the army and pilots were drones? It was. was a throw away line, and they were never shown to be robots or anything on screen. Any production evidence? A quote from a director or actor?

Comment: @cde its day 3 from release, will update as we get more info, but according to the movie they were drones. we have an empty planet, with 3 people on it, 10s of thousands of people on ships.

Comment: It's already out in the us. All my questions are from a post viewing puzzlement

Comment: @cde according to the movie im right, im saying that if interviews and such contradict me later, i will update.

Answer (score 1):

They are the drone-like workforce native to that planet, who were abandoned by whatever smarter beings used to direct them. Krall took control of them.

The "3 of us left" comment is about Krall and his crew, not the species (as Krall was actually human). Krall and the crewmates who survived with him used more mostly-unexplained alien tech and, either intentionally or as a side-effect, came to look like that species.